# How to create a list using foreach - C#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have this class :

```
public class JsonObj
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<JsonObj> children { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? size { get; set; }

}
```

And also this class and a list of the class' objects

```
public class MyObj
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Number {get; set;}
}
```

And suppose `myList` has a number objects of `MyObj`.

Now I'm trying to create a big JsonObj whose children are myList members. That's what I have done so far :

```
var root = new JsonObj
{
   name = "ROOT",
   children = new List<JsonObj>()
   {
     //I suppose I need to use foreach here, but I don't know how to do it.
   }
};
```

How can I create objects using a loop for that list here? Thanks.

Comment: You can not foreach inside the constructor instantiation.  Create the list before this code is called and just assign the list to the children property.

Comment: Why would you need foreach? Do you have a collection of some sort?

Comment: What is the type of `myList` ? what is the relation between `JsonObj` and `MyObj` ?

Comment: @gobes `myList` is type of `MyObj` there is no relation between `JsonObj` and `MyObj`. I just need to convert `myObj` objects to `JsonObj`

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, I have a list.

Comment: "And suppose`myList` has a number objects of `MyObj`." 
Isn't `myList` a list of `MyObj` instances ?

Comment: Does the list contain an exact number of items, or is it variable @jason?

Comment: @FrankerZ it is variable.

Comment: @gobes Yes that's true

Comment: No, Like could it be a variable number of children. Like: Sometimes the `myList` contains 3 items, and sometimes `myList` contains 5 items?

Comment: @FrankerZ I see. It's retrieved from db once, so it's fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use foreach an an initializer. Create your list before JsonObj, and assign it to children, or use LINQ. Here's some examples:

```
var children = new List<JsonObj>();

foreach ( var child in myList )
{
    children.Add(new JsonObj
    {
        name = child.Name,
        size = child.Number
    });
}

var root = new JsonObj
{
   name = "ROOT",
   children = children
};
```

Or LINQ:

```
var root = new JsonObj
{
   name = "ROOT",
   children = myList.Select(child => new JsonObj
   {
       name = child.Name,
       size = child.Number
   }).ToList();
};
```

Here is an example dotnetfiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVcSQV).

Comment: It's a function to get his children. He didn't explain where the children came from, so this is psudeo code.

Comment: Don't you mean `myList` instead of `GetMyChildren()` ?

Comment: The problem is that it's unclear of what OP is asking about. My understanding is that he got a mapping problem between list of `JsonObj`s and list of `MyObj`s...

Comment: OK, using `myList` now instead of `GetMyChildren()`, if OP's childs are in `myList`.

Comment: I did what you said. but it gave this error : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WebApplication2.Controllers.JsonObj' to 'int'

Comment: @jason Edit your original answer with your updated code, and we can help you further.

Comment: Weirdly, first option gave that error, but the second one worked well. Thank you.

Comment: @jason My first option didn't set name/size properly. I've updated my snippet.